# Listar ano no select do ano atual para 10 anos atrás em ordem decrescente

Tags: php

Estou precisando listar em um select os últimos 10 anos. Para isso, estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
<select name="AnoInicio" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Ano</option>
    <?php
       for ($anoInicio = date('Y') - 10; $anoInicio < date('Y'); $anoInicio++)
       {
          echo '<option value="'.$anoInicio.'">'.$anoInicio.'</option>';
       }
    ?>
</select>
```

Ele funciona, mas o problema é que está listando em ordem crescente, ou seja, de 2008 para 2018.

```
2008
2009
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
```

Como eu faço para que ele liste decrescente? de 2018 para 2008?

```
2018
2017
2016
2015
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é mais fácil só gerar os anos de trás pra frente?

```
<?php
$anoInicio = intval(date('Y'));
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++, $anoInicio--) {
    echo '<option value="'.$anoInicio.'">'.$anoInicio.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basta usar a função `rsort()`, se quiser pode criar um array com `range()`.

```
<?php
   $anoAtual = date('Y');
   $anos = range($anoAtual - 10, $anoAtual);
 ?>

<select name="AnoInicio" class="form-control">
<option value="">Ano</option>
<?php
   foreach($anos as $item) printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $item, $item);
 ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: O `range` é uma solução mais elegante. Não tinha pensado nela. :)